# If $n\nmid a,a+d,a+2d. . . a+(n-1)d$,then $(n,d)=1$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

None of the numbers in the sequence $a,a+d,a+2d,a+3d. . . a+(n-1)d$ are divisible by $n$.Then we have to prove that d and n are coprime.

I am supposed to use the pigeonhole principle for this problem.Looking at the equation mod n leads us to finding that the last term is just $a-d$ mod n.But that does not help me go further.I think we are going to use the coefficients of d somewhere,along with the number of remainders.A hint will be appreciated.

Comment: These are $n$ equivalence classes $\mod n$.  Are they all different?  If so, how many of them are mapped to the class containing zero?

Comment: @Eric,I am not yet familiar with equivalence classes.Can you explain without using that terminology?

Comment: In the integers modulo n, the integers are broken up into sets, each of which is composed of numbers congruent to each other modulo n.  We usually denote these sets $[0],[1],[2], \dots [n-1]$, although other notations are common.  $a$ is one of these (we don't have to know which one).  $a+d$ is one of these (and not the same one since the difference is $d$ and we should be assuming $d$ does not divide $n$).  Keep going, arguing that every one of these has a different residue modulo $n$.  You'll end up with $n$ different results mod $n$, one of which must be [0]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(n,d) = 1$.

Then the classes of $ \{\ a,a+d,a+2d. . . a+(n-1)d\ \} $ $\mod(n)$ are all different because if $$n \mid a +hd - (a +kd) \Rightarrow n \mid (h-k)d$$ with $(h-k) < n$ and so $(n,d) \neq 1 $.

But the classes $ \{\ a,a+d,a+2d. . . a+(n-1)d\ \} $ are $n$ and so one is the zero class, for example  $a + ud \equiv 0 \mod n \Rightarrow n \mid a + ud $ and this is a contradiction

Comment: What do you mean when you say that "...the classes {$a,a+d,a+2d...a+(n-1)d$} are $n$".What do you mean by n?Do you mean that there are n elements in that set?

Comment: @rah4927: yes, I mean that there are $n$ elements in that set

Comment: Let me check my understanding.(1)No 2(different) classes can be the same.(2)There are a total of n classes modulo a number n.(3)Then one of them must be the 0 class.(4)But that is not possible.But how does this contradiction lead us to believe that n and d are coprime?I know that the only number that does not have the same number of equivalence classes as the number is 1.Does that help us here?

Comment: @rah4927: are you sure that your statement is correct ?

Comment: @rah4927: I obtain a contradiction with  $n\nmid a,a+d,a+2d. . . a+(n-1)d$

Comment: ,I do not know if the statement is correct but I copied it from an exercise on pigeonhole principle.