# If none of numbers: $a,a+d,a+2d,...,a+(n-1)d$ are divisible by $n$,then prove that $n,d$ are coprime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

> If none of numbers: $a,a+d,a+2d,...,a+(n-1)d$ are divisible by $n$,then prove that $n,d$ are coprime.

Since none of the given numbers are divisible by $n$,then their remainders mod $n$ are $1,2,...,n-1$.Based on pigeon hole principle I deduce that there are two numbers among them such that:
$$a+(i-1)d\equiv a+(j-1)d\pmod n,(0<i,j<n)\Rightarrow$$
$$(i-j)d\equiv 0\pmod n$$
Which means $n|d$ because $i-j<n$.What's wrong with my solution which contradicts the problem??!!

Comment: $2\cdot 3 \equiv 0 \pmod{6} $ and since $2 <6$ by your logic we conclude $6|3$. See the problem?

Comment: @Sil I found my mistake,but what's the correct solution?

Comment: Correct conclusion is that there is a prime $p $ such that $p|n $ and $p|d $, meaning that $(n,d) >1$. In other words they cannot be coprime.

Comment: I'm not sure the problem statement is wrong, as it's been asked sometime ago independently...

Comment: It is wrong, and the other question has it wrong as well. If you look closely at the answer provided there, it shows that assuming they are coprime leads to contradiction, so again, they cannot be coprime.

Comment: @Sil The origin of this problem is from the famous book of Arthur Engel: Problem solving strategies...

Comment: Books have issues, this one probably just meant that $a$ and $d$ are NOT coprime.

Comment: There are already some questions dealing with other errors in the book, for example [Arthur Engel Problem Solving Strategies infinite descent proof contradiction Ch-14 Q11](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202527/arthur-engel-problem-solving-strategies-infinite-descent-proof-contradiction-ch) or [My answer to this combi problem doesn't match the answer in the book (Problem-Solving Strategies)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274011/my-answer-to-this-combi-problem-doesnt-match-the-answer-in-the-book-problem-so?rq=1). Don't trust everything you see in some book...

Comment: Your right,thanks

Answer (score 6):

The problem statement is incorrect.  The conclusion should instead be that $n$ and $d$ are **not** coprime.

Your argument is not quite right, though.  You know $(i-j)d$ is divisible by $n$, but this does not mean $n$ divides $d$ since $n$ may not be prime.

Comment: Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673476/if-n-nmid-a-ad-a2d-an-1d-then-n-d-1 for another restatement of this problem.

Answer (score 3):

A quick counter-example $1, 1+1\cdot2, 1+2\cdot2, 1+3\cdot2=1+(4-1)\cdot2$ none divisible by $4$, but $\gcd(4,2)=2$.

Getting to the conclusion that $(i-j)d\equiv 0\pmod n$ (which is $(i-j)d=n\cdot Q_1$) is good, but not enough as it was pointed already. **Let's assume** that $\gcd(d,n)=1$, this means that $d$ and $n$ has no common factors. So every $p$-prime factor of $n$ [will divide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) $i-j$ (**otherwise** $\gcd(d,n)\geq p >1$), concluding that $n \mid (i-j) < n$ which is a contradiction for $\gcd(d,n)=1$. So $\gcd(d,n)\ne1$.